# ¿Como puedo hacer que un boton me permita pasar de un archivo html a otro? Pasar de una pagina a otra

Tags: javascript, html

Encontré un código en una pregunta que encontré donde dentro de la etiqueta `<button>` usaban `onclick` con `"location.href"` dentro de allí puse el nombre del archivo, así:

```
<body class="page">
  <form action="">
      <header class="Head">
          <img class="image" src="worldimage.png" alt="worldimage.png">
          <br><br><br>
          <h1 class="principal">Hello World!</h1>
          <h3>Welcome to the future</h3>
      </header>
      <section class="zero">
          <br><br>
          <p>Ingrese su usuario</p>
          <input type="text" name="username">
          <p>Ingrrese su contraseña</p>
          <input type="password" name="password">
          <br><br>
          <button class="buttoningress">Ingresar</button>
          <br><br><br><br><br>
          <div>
              <p>Si no tienes una cuenta has click en el boton de acá abajo</p>
              <button class="newaccount" onclick="javascript:location.replace(n2.html)">Crea una cuenta</button> <!--AQUÍ ESTÁ EL PROBLEMA POR EL QUE PREGUNTO -->
          </div>
          <br><br>

      </section>
  </form>
    <br><br><br><br>
    </body>
```

Comment: Y una vez más no sale el codigo :)

Comment: la forma en que pones es correcta, pero también se usa el atributo `href` de la etiqueta `<a>`, puedes ser mas especifico en el problema que tienes?

Comment: No sale el codido? leiste [ask]? te fijaste que cuando escribis en tu pregunta hay una barra que permite formatear el codigo como codigo, asi como otros formatos?

Comment: Sería muy bueno que puedas compartir el código para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Lsito, ahí está

Comment: Pero el button donde lo tienes? lo tienes dentro de un formulario? Déjanos ver el panorama completo al menos del bloque donde está el button.

Comment: Si, esta dentro de un formulario, voy a añadir el codigo completo para que puedas ver mejor

Comment: Mira la respuesta que te planteé y verás que harás con el form y el button.

Answer (score 0):

Más bien quieres hacer esto:

```
javascript:location.replace('n2.html')
```

Te quedaría así:

```
<button class="newaccount" onclick="javascript:location.replace('n2.html')">Crea una cuenta</button>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Bro, hay que agregar algo a ese codigo con javascript? Algo adicional al que pusiste acá

Comment: Yo he probado ese código en jsfiddle y funciona

Answer (score 0):

Deberias colocar esto si el button está dentro del formulario

```
<form class="login-form"  action="tu-url" method="post">
```

y luego cambiar el button por esto

```
<button type="submit" >Crea una cuenta</button>
```

Comment: Que añadiria como url si el proyecto aún esta en mi ordenador y por decirlo de alguna manera no lo he subido aun servidor

Comment: Ah esa parte no habías dicho, en ese caso, intenta colocar la ruta de dicho archivo., Por ejemplo C:/Usuario/Documento/Proyecto/index.html

Comment: Lograste hacerlo?